# How can I get a private key from a mnemonic phrase? in python or other

Tags: web3.py, python, private-key, hd-wallets, private

I have a mnemonic phrase for my wallet. I want to use it in Python. Is there a way to I get a private key from a mnemonic phrase?
I want to get litecoin wallet's private key

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Account` class of `eth_account` by installing the [eth-account](https://pypi.org/project/eth-account/) module in Python:

```shell
pip install eth-account
```

Here's the code:

```py
from eth_account import Account
Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()

# Your mnemonic phrase
mnemonic = "your mnemonic phrase goes here"
private_key = Account.from_mnemonic(mnemonic).privateKey
print("Private Key:", private_key.hex())
```

**P.S., FOR SECURITY PURPOSES, NEVER USE YOUR MNEMONIC OR PRIVATE KEY AS PLAIN TEXT EVER.**